# How do I create multiple drop targets in my Delphi application?

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop

I'm writing a program which has two panels which should serve as drop targets for dropping files. To know what action should be taken upon dropping I need to know which target was used.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DragAcceptFiles(Panel1.Handle, True);
  DragAcceptFiles(Panel2.Handle, True);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  DragAcceptFiles(Panel1.Handle, False);
  DragAcceptFiles(Panel2.Handle, False);
end;

procedure TForm1.WMDropFiles(var Msg: TWMDropFiles);
var
  Filename: PChar;
  Length: LongWord;
begin
  Length:= DragQueryFile(Msg.Drop, 0, NIL, 0);
  Filename:= StrAlloc(Length + 1);
  DragQueryFile(Msg.Drop, 0, Filename, Length + 1);

  // do something with Filename
  ShowMessage(Filename);

  Msg.Result := 0;
  inherited;
end;
```

Two problems with this:

1. While the cursor changes correctly when dragging over the panels the event handler doesn't fire; the showmessage doesn't get called. It does work when I use the form as drop target, however.
2. How can I distinguish between drop targets in the event handler?

Comment: Re 2, you don't necessarily have to do it then, just have a field which records which panel most recently had an OnDragOver event.

Comment: @MartynA - That's an idea, but I guess there must be a proper way to this; like the target's handle in the message's parameters? Thanks for replying, anyway.

Comment: You register the panel window handles to be drop targets, but then try to handle messages sent to the form's window. The form's window isn't going to receive the events. The panel windows are. Further, VCL window recreation is going to screw you over. You probably need to subclass `TPanel` to do it properly. Or use that third party drag/drop library.

Comment: Thanks, David, that makes sense. I'll look into it. Any thoughts on #2?

Comment: It's the exact same problem. Once you have the different panel windows processing the messages, problem 2 vanishes. Think about it. Messages are sent to windows. You have two different windows, panel1 and panel2.

Comment: @David - Got it! Thanks

Comment: @MartynA `OnDragDrop` is for internal drag drop operations, not out of process drops. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  It's far more likely you're right than I am.  I'll keep quiet ,,,

Comment: Maybe this link will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354071

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Subclassing the TPanel works just fine, and isn't overly complicated. Thanks again. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it. (Not that you still need the rep points, but hey... :-))

Comment: You could use the helper function I wrote for exactly this: TWinControl_ActivateDropFiles https://osdn.net/projects/dzlib-tools/svn/view/dzlib/trunk/src/u_dzVclUtils.pas?view=markup&root=dzlib-tools#l1353