# ShowModal on a created Form, no access to modal Form

Tags: delphi, modalpopup

I am using a piece of software that David Heffernan has shared here:

[How can I allow a form to accept file dropping without handling Windows messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354071/)

I have changed the component from a Form to a Panel, and that works fine in the MainForm.

However, when using in a `ShowModal()` environment, I do not have access to the values of components in the modal Form.

I made a small demo to show the problem.

Unit1:

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Unit2;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
  protected
  Public
  End;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
Var aForm: TForm2;
Begin
  aForm := TForm2.Create(Nil);
  Try
    aForm.ShowModal;
  Finally
    aForm.Free;
  End;
End;

End.
```

Unit2:

```pascal
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.StdCtrls, DragAndDrop;

type
  TmyPanel = class(TPanel, IDragDrop)
  private
    FDropTarget: TDropTarget;
    // implement IDragDrop
    function DropAllowed(const FileNames: array of string): Boolean;
    procedure Drop(const FileNames: array of string);
  protected
//    procedure WMDropFiles(var Message: TWMDropFiles); message WM_DROPFILES;
    procedure CreateWindowHandle(Const Params: TCreateParams); override;
    procedure DestroyWindowHandle; override;
  end;

  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    DropRefPanel: TPanel;
    Label1: TLabel;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    DropPanel: TmyPanel;
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TmyPanel.CreateWindowHandle(Const Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited;
  FDropTarget := TDropTarget.Create(WindowHandle, Self);
end;

procedure TmyPanel.DestroyWindowHandle;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FDropTarget);
  inherited;
end;

function TmyPanel.DropAllowed(const FileNames: array of string): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

procedure TmyPanel.Drop(const FileNames: array of string);
Var i: Integer;
begin
//  Form2.Label1.Caption := 'Drop';
  begin
    for i := 0 to Length(FileNames)-1 do
      ShowMessage(Form2.Label1.Caption + ': ' + FileNames[i]);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  showMessage(Label1.Caption);
  Label1.Caption := 'Button';
end;

procedure TForm2.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := 'Activation';
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Label1.Caption := 'FormCreate';

  DropRefPanel.Color := $00BBF7B3 -50;
  DropPanel := TmyPanel.Create(Form2);
  with DropPanel do
  begin
    Parent := DropRefPanel;
    Left := 3;
    Top := 3;
    Width := DropRefPanel.Width - 6;
    Height := DropRefPanel.Height - 6;
    Visible := True;
    ParentBackground := False;
    Color := $00BBF7B3;
    BevelOuter := bvLowered;
    Caption := 'DropBox';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  FreeAndNil(DropPanel);
end;

end.
```

The `DragAndDrop` unit has the unchanged code as made by David.

I have demonstrated the problem here with `Label1`.
When I am in the `Drop()` procedure and ask for the `Form2.Label1.Caption`, it shows the `Label1` value from design-time, or the value as assigned in `FormCreate()`, but not the value from `FormActivate()` or assigned later in the program.

It looks like there are 2 forms.

PS1: Works fine when in the MainForm.

PS2: Changing `Form2` to `nil` in `TmyPanel.Create(Form2)` does not change the behaviour.

PS3: Moving the `Create()` function to `OnActivate` does not change the behaviour.

PS4. I'm using Delphi XE4.

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong in this `ShowModal()` example?

Comment: Does FormActivate exist in the Unit2.dfm file? Alternatively: Set this value in FormCreate: `OnActivate := FormActivate`. I suspect the value assignment has been lost.

Comment: @Usauter Thanks for your reaction. Formactivate does exist in the .dfm file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When showing the modal Form, you are creating a new instance of `TForm2` but not assigning it to the global `Form2` variable that `Drop()` is trying to access. By default, that global variable is used only for an *auto-created* (ie design-time) `TForm2` object, not a dynamically created object.

You are trying to assign the created `TForm2` object as the `Owner` of the `TmyPanel` object, but you are using the global `Form2` variable (which doesn't point at the created `TForm2` object!) when you should be using `FormCreate()`'s implicit `Self` parameter instead, eg:

```pascal
DropPanel := TmyPanel.Create({Form2}Self);
```

Now, `Drop()` can access the Form via the panel's `Owner` property, eg:

```pascal
procedure TmyPanel.Drop(const FileNames: array of string);
var
  i: Integer;
  myFrm: TForm2;
begin
  myFrm := Owner as TForm2;
  myFrm.Label1.Caption := 'Drop';
  begin
    for i := 0 to Length(FileNames)-1 do
      ShowMessage(myFrm.Label1.Caption + ': ' + FileNames[i]);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction. Unfortunately this does not solve my problem. I understand your suggestion. The label1.caption assign in the drop procedure was commented out because I used it for testing. With your suggestion the original label1 on the form is still not changed and I can not access it via de drop-procedure.

Comment: @Jan "*this does not solve my problem*" - Then you have not presented your *actual* problem correctly. Please edit your question to clarify the issue better. However, what I described IS nonetheless a bug in the code you have shown, since `Drop()` is expecting `Form2` to point at a different object than it is actually pointing at. So you need to fix that anyway. "*the original label1 on the form is still not changed*" - why should it change? You commented that out! You are not making much sense. "*I can not access it via de drop-procedure.*" - I showed you exactly how to do that.

Comment: @Jan nevermind, I just saw another bug in your code. I have updated my answer to address that.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Works like a charm. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I commented it out and you did not, so that made the confusion. I played with self, form2 and nil, but had no succes due to the problem that is covered your 1st solution. I am gratefull. PS. I know there is a voting system. How can I vote for you?

Comment: @ remy. I have voted, but need to communicate more before it is actually accepted.

Comment: "I played with self, form2 and nil" - this is no way to go about programming.  Understanding the problem is the best solution.

Comment: @martynA. I agree